# Array manipulation: Convert one array to another

Tags: php

For a few hours, I lost myself in an array.

I have something like this:

```
$results = [
    "User_1" = [ 
        "Step_1" = "accepted",
        "Step_2" = "accepted",
        "Step_3" = "waiting",
        "Step_4" = "refused"
    ],
    "User_2" = [
        "Step_1" = "waiting",
        "Step_2" = "accepted",
        "Step_3" = "accepted",
        "Step_4" = "refused"
    ],
];
```

I need to count (and have the sum) of all the "status" for a specific "Step".

In this case, I wish to have :

```
$steps = [
    "Step_1" = [
        'acceptedSum' => 1,
        'refusedSum' => 0,
        'waitingSum' => 1
    ],
    "Step_2" =[
        'acceptedSum' => 2,
        'refusedSum' => 0,
        'waitingSum' => 0
    ],
    "Step_3" =[
        'acceptedSum' => 1,
        'refusedSum' => 0,
        'waitingSum' => 1
    ],
    "Step_4" =[
        'acceptedSum' => 0,
        'refusedSum' => 0,
        'waitingSum' => 2
    ],
];
```

[ Nota: Number of User is not defined (1 to N) and number of Step too (1 to 4) ]

Any help will be appreciated :)

Thanks to you.

Comment: your output is unclear: add eloborations

Comment: Is it more understandable?

Comment: Why don't you try it first or show us what you have tried?

Comment: You think, I didn't try? I have nothing conclusive... I think array_filters may be the best solution, but the result is so far of what I expected..

Comment: Start out with something like this: `$step_1 = array_count_values(array_column($results, 'Step_1'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, see if it works or not.

```
$steps = array();
$count = 0;
$keys = array_keys(current($results));
foreach($keys as $key){
$accepted = 0;
$refused = 0;
$waiting = 0;
foreach ($results as $result) {
    foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
        if ($key==$k&&$v == 'accepted') {
            $accepted++;
        }
        if ($key==$k&&$v == 'refused') {
            $refused++;
        }
        if ($key==$k&&$v == 'accepted') {
            $waiting++;
        }

    }
}
$new_array = [
    'acceptedSum' => $accepted,
    'refusedSum' => $refused,
    'withoutAnswerSum' => $waiting
];
$steps[$key] = $new_array;
}

print_r($steps);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I fix the output to the right way (see my edit).

Comment: @scoolnico see my updated answer, it should work now according to your format

Comment: Unfortunatly not. With your solution, if I have 15 Users, You have 15 Steps. But the sum seems to be correct.

Comment: how much steps you want?? explain it and how you want to achieve it

Comment: I can have from 1 to 4 steps. But If I have 3 steps for User_1, I have 3 steps too for User_N. In the final result, I want for each step the sum of user who have accepted, refused or not answering.

Comment: couldyou  please explain this with sample data

Comment: Ok, 3 Users and 3 Steps could be a strange exemple. I edit my question.

Comment: is your step is same for all users??

Comment: yes, always. (Edit, done). Thanks for your patience ;)

Comment: Ok, that's what I expect!

Answer (score 2):

You could create the existing keys dynamically. The missing keys you could add with a value of 0;

```
$results = [
    "User_1" => [
        "Step_1" => "accepted",
        "Step_2" => "accepted",
        "Step_3" => "waiting"
    ],
    "User_2" => [
        "Step_1" => "waiting",
        "Step_2" => "accepted",
        "Step_3" => "accepted"
    ],
    "User_3" => [
        "Step_1" => "refused",
        "Step_2" => "refused",
        "Step_3" => "waiting"
    ]
];

$steps = [];
$status = [];

foreach ($results as $result) {
    foreach ($result as $key => $r) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $steps)) {
            $steps[$key] = [];
        }
        if (!array_key_exists($r."Sum", $steps[$key])) {
            $steps[$key][$r."Sum"] = 0;
        }
        $steps[$key][$r."Sum"]++;
        $status[] = $r;
    }
}

foreach (array_unique($status) as $au) {
    foreach ($steps as &$step) {
        if (!array_key_exists($au."Sum", $step)) {
            $step[$au."Sum"] = 0;
        }
    }
}

print_r($steps);
```

[Php output demo](https://3v4l.org/8euQr)

Answer (score 0):

I think the output in your question is wrong, but are you looking for something like this

```
<?php

$results = [
    "User_1" => [
        "Step_1" => "accepted",
        "Step_2" => "accepted",
        "Step_3" => "waiting"
    ],
    "User_2" => [
        "Step_1" => "waiting",
        "Step_2" => "accepted",
        "Step_3" => "accepted"
    ],
    "User_3" => [
        "Step_1" => "refused",
        "Step_2" => "refused",
        "Step_3" => "waiting"
    ]  
];

function sumByStatus($array, $status) {
    $filtered_array = array_filter($array,function($value) use ($status) {
        return $value === $status;
    });

    return count($filtered_array);
}

$newResult = array_map(function($item) {
    return [
        'acceptedSum' => sumByStatus($item, 'accepted'),
        'refusedSumF' => sumByStatus($item, 'refused'),
        'withoutAnswerSum' => sumByStatus($item, 'waiting')
    ];
}, $results);

print_r($newResult);
```

The output is

```
Array
(
    [User_1] => Array
        (
            [acceptedSum] => 2
            [refusedSum] => 0
            [withoutAnswerSum] => 1
        )

    [User_2] => Array
        (
            [acceptedSum] => 2
            [refusedSum] => 0
            [withoutAnswerSum] => 1
        )

    [User_3] => Array
        (
            [acceptedSum] => 0
            [refusedSum] => 2
            [withoutAnswerSum] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I fix the output to the right way (see my edit).